# Getting an error like you forgot to wrap the component in provider

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authorization, auth0, relayjs

I have the below component like a wrapper, and the code looks like as below,

```
export const Wrapper: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => (
  <StrictMode>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN}
      clientId={import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID}
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
      }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<Spin />}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <RelayEnvironmentProvider environment={useEnvironment()}> // Here I am calling that useEnvironment from the below component
            {children}
          </RelayEnvironmentProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Suspense>
    </Auth0Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

I have another component, `relay-enironment`and the code looks like as below.

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import {
  Environment,
  Network,
  RecordSource,
  Store,
  Observable,
  RequestParameters,
  Variables,
  FetchFunction,
} from "relay-runtime";   
import { createClient } from "graphql-sse";

const fetchFn = (accessToken: string): FetchFunction => {
  return async (request, variables) => {
   // fetch function
    });
    return await resp.json();
  };
};

const subscribeFn: any = (operation: RequestParameters, variables: Variables) =>
  ..... // subscriptions
  });

const createRelayEnvironment = (accessToken: string) =>
  new Environment({
    network: Network.create(fetchFn(accessToken), subscribeFn),
    store: new Store(new RecordSource()),
  });

export const useEnvironment = () => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  return useMemo(() => {
    let accessToken: string | null = null;

    getAccessTokenSilently()
      .then((token) => {
        accessToken = token;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching access token:", error);
      });

    return createRelayEnvironment(accessToken || "");
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);
};
```

And I am getting the error like

> Uncaught Error: You forgot to wrap your component in `Auth0Provider`.

Even though I call that useEnvironment component in the wrapper component, I am getting the above error. Please suggest suggestions on how to fix the issue.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Where are you calling useEnvironment?

Comment: @Abe  I am calling `useEnvironment` in the wrapper component, and the code is in the question for the same.

Comment: The wrapper component contains the Auth0 provider, so it is by nature outside of it. You must call the hook from a component nested inside the provider.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code snippet, if possible